# Get an alias address in the sender field in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Let's say I have two Google accounts: `perso@gmail.com` and `pro@gmail.com`.

I am connected to Gmail on my `perso` account. I have added `pro` as an alias address to send mail as, in the Gmail settings (Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as).

But, when I select the `pro@gmail.com` address when sending a mail, some of my contacts sometimes still see the original, `perso@gmail.com` address. And by checking the raw message, apparently, `perso@gmail.com` is still used in the `Sender:` field; `pro@gmail.com` is only present in the `From:` field.

How to make it so that the persons I send mail to *never* see the address `perso@gmail.com`? I tried checking and unchecking "Treat as an alias" in the Gmail settings, but this did not change.

Answer (score 0):

not possible. even if its set up like this:

[image]

it will still shows (under **Show Original**) which account was an initial sender; and the initial sender is also shown if it was sent from a delegate account

Comment: well, yes, it looks like this, and yet the `Sender:` field in the mail uses the wrong mail. The `From:` field is correct. You can check it yourself by sending a mail from your alias and then going to the "View original" option in the sent mail.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier you are right. I even tried to send it from my delegate account and it still shows my supreme email but now in `X-Google-Sender-Delegation:` ... my conclusion - it's not possible to anonymize it